# I upload my Laravel project to GitHub but unfortunately the .env file didn't uploaded. how we can upload it with my project?

Tags: laravel, github, .env

recently I used the GitHub to uppload my project on it. but when another my friend want to sync with my project he can't find the .env file

how should I do now?

Comment: You should **not** add your `.env` file to version control. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: @brombeer it's safe to add to version control just as long as you encrypt it first. See my answer.

Comment: @iH8 Oh, thanks for the insight, haven't been using Laravel since v8. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

As Shiva answered, the file is ignored by git because it's mentioned in your .gitignore file. You could remove it from the file so you can upload it as long as you are aware of the security implications. A better option would be to encrypt it. Since Laravel v9.23 you can encrypt your .env file with Artisan using `env:encrypt` and decrypt with `env:decrypt`

> Unencrypted environment files should never be stored in source control. However, Laravel allows you to encrypt your environment files so that they may safely be added to source control with the rest of your application.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#encryption

Answer (score 1):

Check your .gitignore file.
I think this is included in .gitignore file so that it is not included and not uploaded to github.
Since, .env file includes your project specific secrets and configurations, it shouldnot be exposed to others.
However, If you want to upload it anyway, remove its entry on .gitignore file. This may resolve your issue.